# free public repository of XML reference test data

Tags: xml, unit-testing, parsing, repository, reference

I need to test a parser and I am looking for public sample well-formed and malformed XML data.

Does someone know about a free public repository of XML reference sample data?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the W3C [XML Conformance Test Suites](http://www.w3.org/XML/Test/) (2000 test files).

Also, to test well-formed XML documents, you could use the [XML Schema Test Suite](http://www.w3.org/XML/2004/xml-schema-test-suite/index.html). The 40000 documents are used to check XML schema validators, but I guess they can also be used to check simple XML parsers.

Comment: Thank you very much. this perfectly answers my question :-)